# Yii2 Display Image In Pop Up On Click Image

Tags: gridview, yii2, popup

I have a gridview that show a thumbnail of image that has been saved into mysql.I need to show the images as popup when it clicked.

This is the view of my gridview in **index.php**
[image]

and this is the code [UPDATE]

```
<?php
<div class="license-index">

<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
<?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

<p>
    <?= Html::a('Create License', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</p>

<?=
GridView::widget([
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'pjax' => true,
    'pjaxSettings' => [
        'neverTimeout' => true,
        'options' => [
            'id' => '-pjax',
            'enableReplaceState' => false,
            'enablePushState' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
            'header' => 'No',
            'options' => [
                'width' => '10px',
            ],
        ],
        'company',
        'address',
        [
            'attribute' => 'bukti',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                return Html::a(Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web') . '/file/' . $data->bukti, ['alt' => 'some', 'class' => 'fancy-box', 'height' => '100px', 'width' => '100px']), ['site/zoom']);
    },
    'format' => ['raw'],
        ],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]);
?>
</div>
<?php 
$this->registerJs('jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("a.fancy-box").fancybox();
});');
?>
```

**How do I can display that image as popup when it's clicked?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery plugin like this one:
http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

It's very easy to setup (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html)

Add the plugin's resources

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css">
<script src="magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
```

then add this piece of code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thing').magnificPopup({type:'image'});
});
```

Hope that will be helpful!

Comment: It didn't work. It's give `The image could not be loaded`.

Comment: where did this message appear?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use any modal box plugin (for example http://fancybox.net/, https://github.com/newerton/yii2-fancybox-3) and initialize by class name.

```
$this->registerJsFile('modalJs');
$this->registerCssFile('modalCss')

[
    'attribute' => 'bukti',
    'value' => function ($data) {
                return Html::a(Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web') . '/file/' . $data->bukti, ['alt' => 'some', 'class' => 'fancy-box', 'height' => '100px', 'width' => '100px']), ['site/zoom']);
     },
    'format' => ['raw'],
] 

$this->registerJs('jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("a.fancy-box").fancybox();
});')
```

Comment: It's doesn't work. I wish you can take a look my full code. I've update the code. Thanks

Comment: You need to register Js and css resources at the beginning of the file 
    $this->registerCssFile('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.css');
    $this->registerJsFile('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.js');